# C# method prototype like in C++

Tags: c#, prototype

Can I somehow make a prototype of method and declare its body in C# like I do in C++?

For example in C++:

```
void foo();

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}

void foo(){
    cout << "im foo";
}
```

How can I achieve it in C#?

Comment: C# uses a multipass compiler, so you *don't* have to do stuff like this. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Its just all about the readability. I want to have something like list of all methods at one place so I don't have to jump through the code.

Comment: Well, use the IDE for that, it can provide that list without requiring you to write it in the first place.

Comment: How can i do it in VS Community 2015?

Comment: I don't know it it's there in community edition, but I suppose it should. You've got it in the [solution explorer](https://i.imgur.com/sizizTI.png) or just [above the code editor](https://i.imgur.com/hqGgyoW.png)

Comment: A way you can increase readability - and reduce the tightness of coupling - is to declare interfaces, which do just list methods and properties, and then your concrete implementations just interact with the world through those interfaces.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: @Slajni See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are partial methods in C#, which I think is quite similar.

Partial methods must be `private` and return `void`. If your methods are not private or do not return `void`, consider using the second approach below.

Here's an example of a partial method:

```
partial class MyClass {
    partial void Foo();
}

// This can be in another file
partial class MyClass  {
    partial void Foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }
}
```

---

Another approach is to use interfaces:

```
interface IFoo {
    void Foo();
}

class MyClass: IFoo {
    public void Foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }
}
```

---

However, if you just want to see all the methods in a class in a neat way, Visual Studio can already do that for you. I don't have Visual Studio on the computer that I'm currently using so here's a screenshot I found on Google:

[image]

The part where it says "RunFile(PythonEngine engine...)" is where you want to click. After you clicked All the methods in the current file will be displayed. You can click on one of them to jump to it!